# If $f(n)=\omega(g(n))$ then exists $h(n)$ so $h(n)=\omega(g(n))$ and $f(n)=\omega(h(n))$?

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

> True or false: If $f(n)=\omega(g(n))$ then exists $h(n)$ so $h(n)=\omega(g(n))$ and $f(n)=\omega(h(n))$?

I think this is true but can't seem to prove it. I tried playing around with the definition that from some $n$: $f(n)>c\cdot g(n)$ but I didn't really get anywhere.

Comment: $\omega$ a function or does it have a special neaning?

Comment: @WilliamElliot in Asymptotic Analysis $\omega$ means that $f(n)$ is an order or magnitude larger than $g(n)$. The definition I know is that for every constant $c$ exists $n_0$ such that for each $n > n_0$ $f(n)>c\cdot g(n)$